# Issue On Selecting Only Elements which has Children

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why the code adding `<i class="red"> + </i>` to all `<li>`s under the child `<ul>`. What I would like to do is just adding `+` to `<li>`(s) which contain a new set of `<ul>` but as you can see it is adding to all children

```js
 $(function() {
   $('li:has(ul)').find('span').append('<i class="red"> + </i>');
  });
```

```css
.red{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Item 2-1</span></li>
      <li><span>Item 2-2</span></li>
      <li><span>Item 2-3</span></li>
      <li><span>Item 2-4</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a descendent `>` selector:

```js
$(function() {
  $('body > ul > li:has(ul)').find('> span').append('<i class="red"> + </i>');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Item 2-1</span></li>
      <li><span>Item 2-2</span></li>
      <li><span>Item 2-3</span></li>
      <li><span>Item 2-4</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen, this is exactly what I was looking for justa quick question? is there any wat to append the `+` before the text inside  the `<span>`

Comment: @Behseini Use `prepend` instead of `append`. Simple. `:)`

Comment: Sure, Thanks again

Comment: @Behseini Don't hesitate to ask, if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

It is because .find is looking for all span elements that are a descendent of the li element. As mentioned in the description [here](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

The following solution is what you are looking for

```
$(function() {
  $('li:has(ul)').children('span').append('<i class="red"> + </i>');
});
```

Which targets just the children of the li element
[Demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/p8W4kN7V5IgzAd39i5k3?p=preview)